# how to use the contract instance for multiple functions?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, testing, mocha

I am trying to test the exchange where two types of tokens are trading. I want to set those tokens in exchange and trying to trade them between two accounts, but i am unable to get the updated instance of my contract, due to which i am getting error like "this abc is not a function"

Comment: Please post the logs?

Comment: I have two token contracts name A and B as a token contract and another contract as an Exchange where these two tokens A and B will be traded. I am trying to test this scenario when these tokens will get traded and the final value of respective tokens will be changed.

Comment: When i am trying to deploy the instance of exchange contract, i am unable to use the same instance for multiple functions of the same exchange contract.